# SVN: Sync file between repositories

Tags: svn

A company uses SVN for code management. Currently there are two main repositories which are completely separate from each other: DEV repository and QA repository. A request was made for one of the files from QA now to be used in DEV. There is a problem: since both repositories are separate, any changes made by QA to the file would have to be merged purely by hand to DEV, for the rest of time. Is there a way to automate this process through SVN? That is, when QA commits any changes to that file, the DEV would uptake those changes automatically? Much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html). It might be suitable.